Four functions theorem
In the proof of the four functions theorem (see this for example), one usually makes the following assumption wlog: the functions $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ considered vanish outside the corresponding families $$\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B},\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}
$$
and $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{P}([n])$, where $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the power set. Then one proceed with the proof by induction on this case, and claims that the general case follows from this particular case.
Is anybody familiar with the topic able to explain why this much more simplified setting implies the general one? I do not see how modifying the functions as such helps.

Actually, I think I got it: denoting the modified version of, say, $\alpha$, as $\alpha_{\mathcal{A}}$, then the hypothesis is still valid (I realised there might be a typo in the reference, it should be for all $A, B\subseteq N$ without splitting in the two families), and $\sum_{S\in\mathcal{P}([n])}\alpha_{\mathcal{A}}(S)=\sum_{S\in\mathcal{A}}\alpha(S)$, and similarly for the other functions correspondingly defined. This should be how we use the modified functions to recover the general statement from the one applying only to $\mathcal{P}(n)$.
